# Bouncing Ball SKPhysicsBody - Stop Bouncing Perpendicular Forever

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sprite-kit

So I'm making a brick break style game using "[Ray Wenderlich's amazing tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/123393/how-to-create-a-breakout-game-with-sprite-kit-and-swift)" in `Spritekit`/`Swift`, just like the tutorial.

I successfully have a ball bouncing around the screen using a `SKSpriteNode()` and `SKPhysicsBody()` and I've been tweaking values for the `impulses` used to begin the ball bouncing around the screen forever.

**However**, I stumbled upon a problem which I hope to find a solution.

Sometimes, in my game, the `Sprite` will bounce around and become "**Wall Locked**" bouncing almost Perpendicular (or straight) between two walls, (give or take a few pixels)! So ends up Zig-Zagging across the whole screen between two said walls for ages.

What I want to do is, should this happen and the ball get "Wall Locked" to introduce a new impulse to get it moving again...

How can this be done? For example, if it has bounced between the top and bottom walls 10 times, then it's time to adjust it's angle/introduce a new impulse.

Could the last 10 positions be stored in an array, then test if their almost perpendicular somehow?

Comment: In that tutorial download the source from part 2 and open _Playing.swift_ take a look at the `updateWithDeltaTime` method.  This already contains velocity regulation code for the ball, experiment with that.

Answer (score 1):

If you inspect the **velocity** property of your Sprite, you could detect when either of its values is close to zero and then make them something that is not so close to zero. This would stop it getting stuck moving just horizontally or vertically.